# Any reasons not to upload / import gmail contacts into Twitter?

Tags: security, twitter, google-contacts

If I did give my Twitter account access to my my gmail contacts will I be able to control what happens with my information? I ask because I'm a bit worried Twitter might just automatically email everyone in my contact list or something similar.

Comment: You give access? You mean you give them the credentials of your Twitter profile?

Comment: If I gave Twitter access to my gmail contacts, apparently Twitter will connect me with friends / people I know by using 'email addresses' from my contact list. My uncertainty is that I don't know 'how' Twitter does this. For example: Will Twitter automatically notify people from my contact list?  Or will Twitter 'notify me' with something similar to => "Hey, here are people you know" and let me choose what action to take?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much they're going to do exactly what you're thinking.  Twitter and other social media websites get more hits from people if they randomly spam them like crazy.  My mother did that non-sense and I got spam from Facebook like crazy telling me to join as if it were her.  While they might currently say that you will get control over what happens to your contact information, they also say that they can change their Terms Of Service (TOS) at any time they choose.  Personally, I see no point in trusting them in what they say.  If you have a large amount of people that you need to add to your Twitter contact list, it would be best to add them one at a time to avoid any potential issues that Twitter might have.

There's also the small little detail of the possibility that they might get hacked in the future, and if your credentials are there, (potentially in plain text), then you're more than likely going to get your email hacked as well.  Mind you, if you keep the same credentials for both Twitter and your email you may get hacked anyways due to your bad password decisions.

Comment: You mentioned that I could (add them one at a time) manually. When I try your suggestion, searching (using an email address) Twitter's search engine always replies with (No results).  Is there a way to find people on Twitter by searching for them with their email address?

Comment: Only if they allow it.  The Twitter website has more information [here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170001#).